# Dry jQuery for hiding and showing divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to figure out a way to dry up this code.  I am trying to hide one div as another appears.  I was thinking a for loop but can not figure out a way to hide as I toggle another in the same loop.  Each div should hide separately, not all at once.

Thanks from a javaScript beginner.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

$(".hide").hide();

$("#pic0").click(function(){
    $("#text0").slideToggle("fast");
    $("#pic0").hide();
  });

  $("#text0").click(function(){
    $("#pic0").slideToggle("fast");
    $("#text0").hide();

  });

  $("#pic1").click(function(){
    $("#text1").slideToggle("fast");
    $("#pic1").hide();
 
  });

  $("#text1").click(function(){
    $("#pic1").slideToggle("fast");
    $("#text1").hide();

  });

  $("#pic2").click(function(){
    $("#text2").slideToggle("fast");
    $("#pic2").hide();


    
  });

  $("#text2").click(function(){
    $("#pic2").slideToggle("fast");
    $("#text2").hide();

  });
  
  });
```

```css
.first {
  background-color: black;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
 }

.hide {
  background-color: red;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="first" id="pic0"></div>
<div class="hide" id="text0"></div>

<div class="first" id="pic1"></div>
<div class="hide" id="text1"></div>

<div class="first" id="pic2"></div>
<div class="hide" id="text2"></div>
```

Comment: I haven't *dried* code before, anyways you should use a loop or a classes `hide` and `first`.

Comment: Harijoe (below) may be correct, that the jQueryUI accordian widget may be what you are looking for. However, to see how to do what you wish by *using the jQuery "starts with" selector*, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/ymayo1by/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".hide").hide();

    $(".first").click(function () {
        $(this).next('.hide').slideToggle('fast')
        .siblings('.hide:visible').slideUp('fast');
    });

});
```

**EDIT:** fixed `toggle` issue on the active item.

Comment: Yes this is awesome! It looks so much better this way.  This would get rid of the need for the id attribute then?Thanks!

Comment: Yep, no id is needed for that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are doing this as an exercise to learn javascript or because you need it in a development project, but [jQuery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible) seems to achieve exactly what you describe.

Example : [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/z3Ltabd7/1/)

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your HTML and group the sets like:

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="first pic" id="pic0"></div>
    <div class="hide text" id="text0"></div>
</div>

<div class="group">
    <div class="first pic" id="pic1"></div>
    <div class="hide text" id="text1"></div>
</div>
```

You can modify your javascript as:

```
$('.pic').on('click', function () {
    $(this).siblings('.text').slideToggle("fast");
    $(this).hide();
});

$(".text").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.pic').slideToggle("fast");
    $(this).hide();
});
```

here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zz7mt93o/1/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you would have to improve your markup, such as group it to make it easier to deal with via JS/jQuery. I have come up with a dirty version which doesn't need you to change the markup. See if this works for you.

```
$(".hide").hide();
$("[id^='pic'], [id^='text']").click(function() {
    var id = this.id.slice(0, -1);
    var $which = id==="text" ? $(this).prev() : $(this).next();
    $(this).hide();
    $which.slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Demo@[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/xo3rduq6/1/)

Slightly improved version @ [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/xo3rduq6/2/)

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you have requested:

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ngjdby0y/)

```
$('div[id^="pic"]').click(function(){
    var num = this.id.slice(-1); //returns final char: 0, 1, 2, etc
    $('#text'+num).slideToggle('fast');
    $(this).hide();
});
$('div[id^="text"]').click(function(){
    var num = this.id.slice(-1); //returns final char: 0, 1, 2, etc
    $('#pic'+num).slideToggle('fast');
    $(this).hide();
});
```

You can avoid the annoying bouncing of the divs as they show/hide by (1) wrapping them in containing divs that (2) have a fixed height.  [See this slight modification to the previous jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ngjdby0y/1/)

Notes:

1. We used the "starts with" css/jQuery selector to bind, for example, first click event to all DIVs whose ID begins with "pic"...
2. `this.id` (native javascript) is faster than using `$(this)` and results in identical value
3. We `slice` off the final character, stick into var `num`, and then use that to identify the correct `text` or `pic` div to toggle